# How to send Minecraft Server packets from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, network-protocols, minecraft, packets

I did take a look at the question [Sending Packets to Minecraft Server: Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859049/sending-packets-to-minecraft-server-objective-c)

It could have been related if they used this link here: [Protocol - Minecraft Server](http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol) however, They did not use that. They used the wiki which is mainly for general information. The one i am referencing is for creating a new client. However, When i asked on the IRC. They talked like i knew nothing. So, I ask here.

```
 How do i Send the packet correctly with the fields to Minecraft server?
```

Please note, The codes for Minecraft Server are on the website.

The code i have, Connects to the server, The output on Minecraft server looks like this:

```
 [INFO] Disconnecting /192.168.1.4:60911: Took too long to log in
 [INFO] Disconnecting /192.168.1.4:60915: Took too long to log in
 [INFO] Disconnecting /192.168.1.4:60927: Took too long to log in
 [INFO] /192.168.1.4:60934 lost connection
 [INFO] Disconnecting /192.168.1.4:60954: Took too long to log in
```

How do i send these packets correctly?

```
 NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    unsigned char *ch[] = {0x02, [[defs stringForKey:@"Username"] UTF8String]};
    UInt8 i = (UInt8)ch;
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&i length:sizeof(i)];


    NSString *reqLog = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [asyncsocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

    //[asyncsocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket LFData] withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

    [asyncsocket readDataToLength:5 withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

    /*NSData *responseTerminatorData = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

     [asyncsocket readDataToData:responseTerminatorData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];*/
```

FINAL NOTE: IOS5 is the platform for this application

Comment: This question is too general.  First identify the classes you want to use and then attempt to implement the Minecraft network protocol and then come back with specific issues you are having.

Comment: Ok, I need to know how to send the packets with the fields. I don't know how to send for example, 0x01 with Protocol version and username.

Comment: Then you need to learn about network programming, including IP protocols, network byte ordering, blocking, etc.  This is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I need to have a example of how to do this, I am learning of how to do byte ordering. But, Not many examples are out there for objective-c.